# How to conditionally limit results based on a single column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working in a 3rd Party DB which uses row versioning heavily. Usually this isn't an issue, but with a particular dataset it is due to the loose business rules on the front end. As you will notice, the `INNER JOIN` is used to get the group of rows with the most recent `EffectiveDate` for each `EmpID`. This logic should always be used unless there is a row where `EnrollmentStatus = 'Enrolled'`. If this exists, then this group of rows should be returned. By group of rows I mean `EmpID` and `EffectiveDate`.

In the data set below the desired results would be the 4 rows where `EffectiveDate = '2015-12-15'` since it contains the record where `EnrollmentStatus = 'Enrolled'`. If no records for each `EmpID` have a `EnrollmentStatus = 'Enrolled'` then the inner join will suffice.

I'm sure I'm overlooking the elegant way to do this.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#emp') is not null drop table #emp

create table #emp
    (EmpID int, 
    EmpBenID int,
    EffectiveDate datetime,
    EligibilityDate datetime,
    EnrollBeginDate datetime,
    OverrideEnrollBeginDate datetime,
    EnrollEndDate datetime,
    OverrrideEnrollEndDate datetime,
    EnrollStatus varchar(64))

insert into #emp(EmpID, EmpBenID, EffectiveDate, EligibilityDate, EnrollBeginDate,OverrideEnrollBeginDate,EnrollEndDate,OverrrideEnrollEndDate,EnrollStatus) 
values
(1950,55403,'2015-12-15 00:00:00','1998-11-02 00:00:00',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Not Enrolled'),
(1950,55404,'2015-12-15 00:00:00','1998-11-02 00:00:00','1998-12-01 00:00:00',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Enrolled'),
(1950,55405,'2015-12-15 00:00:00','1998-11-02 00:00:00',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Not Enrolled'),
(1950,55406,'2015-12-15 00:00:00','1998-11-02 00:00:00',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Not Enrolled'),
(1950,55407,'2016-01-12 00:00:00','1998-11-02 00:00:00',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Not Enrolled'),
(1950,55408,'2016-01-12 00:00:00','1998-11-02 00:00:00','2011-01-19 00:00:00',NULL,'2011-08-31 00:00:00',NULL,'Not Enrolled'),
(1950,55409,'2016-01-12 00:00:00','1998-11-02 00:00:00',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Not Enrolled'),
(1950,55410,'2016-01-12 00:00:00','1998-11-02 00:00:00',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Not Enrolled')


select e.* 
from #emp e
inner join
(select EmpID, Max(EffectiveDate) dt
from #emp
--Attempted multiple filtering methods here while trying to avoid a sub-select
group by EmpID) e2 on e2.EmpID = e.EmpID and e2.dt = e.EffectiveDate
```

Comment: sorry, but still dont understand the logic behind your problem. Your sample is incomplete should have empID with both cases also include the expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry you don't understand @JuanCarlosOropeza. I can include the expected result if it will help you, but i noted what the expected or desired result should be in the OP. The sample is complete, and would only be replicated for other EmpIDs i can assure you.

Comment: Again, I already say I didnt understand it. And your description of the problem wasnt complete otherwise the answers below wouldnt have to guess what result you want.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry you feel that way, but they seemed to nail it. Cheers.

Comment: Dont worry for my feeling, you are lucky Gordon Jedi powers found the androids you were looking for. But even him wasnt sure what your want. Is just a friendly advice try to work a litle more in your question so we dont have to guess.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I tried to make it as clear as possible. I even gave the DDL and populated the tables which maybe 1% of people do.  I admit it's not a typical question and therefore hard to understand. However, it isn't due to lack of effort / work to make it as clear as possible. I can assure you that I have read the How-to-Ask and spaghettidba, which is a favorite of Sean Lange and others including myself--though they are usually more appropriately referenced in my opinion. I am, however, thankful for Gordon's and everyone's answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using window functions, but that is another matter.  If I understand correctly, you want this logic:

```
select e.* 
from #emp e inner join
     (select EmpID,
             coalesce(max(case when EnrollmentStatus = 'Enrolled' then EffectiveDate end), 
                      max(EffectiveDate)
                     ) dt
      from #emp
--Attempted multiple filtering methods here while trying to avoid a sub-select
      group by EmpID
     ) e2
     on e2.EmpID = e.EmpID and e2.dt = e.EffectiveDate;
```

This gets the date for `'Enrolled'`, if it exists.  Otherwise, it gets the maximum date.

Comment: But that will result in only 1 record with `Enrolled` . I think he wants "The maximum date available or **all** the records with 'Enrolled'"

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is close to what I was trying using `MAX(COALSECE())` but I was just thinking backwards. Your solution works so far--and i expect it to on the larger data set. Mind elaborating on your window functions method?

Comment: @scsimon . . . The window function would calculate the maximum date and the maximum enrolled date as separate variables, and then use a `where` clause to choose the best one.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
select EmpID, EffectiveDate
from #emp e1
where EnrollStatus = 'Enrolled'
union
select e1.EmpID, max(e1.EffectiveDate)
from #emp e1
where e1.EnrollStatus <> 'Enrolled'
and not exists (select 1 from #emp e2 where e1.EmpID = e2.EmpID and e2.EnrollStatus = 'Enrolled')
group by e1.EmpID
```

It gets the effective date for those enrolled, and the max effective date for those not enrolled (and who do not have a status of enrolled at any point)

Comment: Can you explain? You are aggregating in your union but missing a `GROUP BY`

Comment: @scsimon Whoops, my bad, try that

Comment: Thanks. This does limit the data to the correct effective date but would require another join in the end. +1 from me.